# send data with retrofit2 in kotlin in nested json format

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2

I need to post data with nested Json as screen below (see "user" and then the data )

```
{
  "user" : 
  {
    "email": "xxxxx",
    "password" : "surabaya1234"
  }
}
```

currently my retrofit is working with this format

```
{
  "email": "xxxxx",
  "password" : "surabaya1234"  
}
```

this is my retrofitClient

```
object RetrofitClient {
    private const val BASE_URL = "http://X.X.X.X"

    private val okHttpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .addInterceptor { chain ->
            val original = chain.request()
            val requestBuilder = original.newBuilder()
                .addHeader("Authorization", token)
                .method(original.method(), original.body())
            val request = requestBuilder.build()
            chain.proceed(request)
        }.build()

    val instance: Api by lazy {
        val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .client(okHttpClient)
            .build()

        retrofit.create(Api::class.java)
    }
}
```

this is my buttonListener, it send the data when it pressed

```
binding.buttonSignUp.setOnClickListener {
  val email = editTextEmail.text.toString().trim()
  val phoneNumber = editTextPhone.text.toString().trim()
  val password = editTextPassword.text.toString().trim()
  val passwordConfirmation = editTextPassword.text.toString().trim()
  if (email.isEmpty()) {
      editTextEmail.error = "Email Required"
      editTextEmail.requestFocus()
      return@setOnClickListener
  }
  RetrofitClient.instance.createUser(email, password, phoneNumber).enqueue(object: Callback<User>{
      override fun onFailure(call: Call<User>, t: Throwable) {
          toast = Toast.makeText(activity,"Not OK",Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
      }
      override fun onResponse(call: Call<User>, response: Response<User>) {
          toast = Toast.makeText(activity,"Sukses",Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
      }

  })
```

this is Interface

```
interface Api {
    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("users")
    fun createUser(
        @Field("email") email:String,
        @Field("password") password:String
    ):Call<User>
}
```

how do I change my code probably Interface so it can send the data in nested json format like sample above, this probably simple answer, but I'm new in kotlin / java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a model also and pass the model to retrofit it will get the work done for you automatically.

Create model accordingly the json structure.

```
public class UserLogin {

 @SerializedName("user")
 @Expose
 private User user;

 public User getUser() {
 return user;
 }

 public void setUser(User user) {
 this.user = user;
 }

}

public class User {

 @SerializedName("email")
 @Expose
 private String email;
 @SerializedName("password")
 @Expose
 private String password;

 public String getEmail() {
 return email;
 }

 public void setEmail(String email) {
 this.email = email;
 }

 public String getPassword() {
 return password;
 }

 public void setPassword(String password) {
 this.password = password;
 }

}
```

Change your api interface

```
interface Api {
    @POST("users")
    fun createUser(
        @Body userLogin : UserLogin
    ):Call<User>
}
```

and while making api call just call like this.

```
//create a user login model and set the data, and pass it in below method
 RetrofitClient.instance.createUser(userLogin).enqueue(object: Callback<User>{
      override fun onFailure(call: Call<User>, t: Throwable) {
          toast = Toast.makeText(activity,"Not OK",Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
      }
      override fun onResponse(call: Call<User>, response: Response<User>) {
          toast = Toast.makeText(activity,"Sukses",Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
      }

  })
```

Comment: thank you, I followed all your instructions above and already and compile success, but when I test and send the data it show and error as follow "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: @Body parameters cannot be used with form or multi-part encoding. (parameter #1)  for method Api.createUser",

Comment: try removing the @FormUrlEncoded tag then check again

Answer (score 1):

If you want to send data as you want, try this.

```
interface Api {
    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("users")
    fun createUser(
        @FieldMap HashMap<String, Object> param
    ):Call<User>
}
```

and add map where you send retrofit.

```
val hashMap = HashMap()
hashMap.put("user", sendData) //make sendData String from json
val responseBodyCall = RetrofitConnectionAPI.setConnect().createUser(hashMap)
```

ps. making JSONObject

```
val jsonData = JSONObject()
jsonData.put("email", email)   // inputed email
jsonData.put("password", password) // inputed password
val sendDate = jsonData.toString()
```

Comment: thank you, based with my data (email and password) can you give sample "make sendData String from json" ,  sorry I'm new with kotlin

Comment: I added making JSON